# Log de Banco SQL em Restoring Pending

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um banco SQL que foi acessado por alguma outra pessoa e ele entrou em "Restoring Pending" assim que acessaram. Existe alguma forma de extrair algum log ou qualquer outra maneira mais detalhada de saber como, quem e quando foi feito?

Answer (score 0):

O `SQL Server` tem um log dessas ações, no caso do restore, na tablea `restorehistory`.

Aqui uma query que vai mostrar o último restore para cada database, deve te ajudar:

```
WITH LastRestores AS
(
SELECT
    DatabaseName = [d].[name] ,
    [d].[create_date] ,
    [d].[compatibility_level] ,
    [d].[collation_name] ,
    r.*,
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.Name ORDER BY r.[restore_date] DESC)
FROM master.sys.databases d
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.[restorehistory] r ON r.[destination_database_name] = d.Name
)
SELECT *
FROM [LastRestores]
WHERE [RowNum] = 1
```

Créditos: [how-to-query-last-restore-date-in-sql-server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/how-to-query-last-restore-date-in-sql-server/33705)